# Duda sobre búsqueda en la base de datos

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Soy nuevo programando en Ruby on Rails y quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente: Estoy intentando realizar la búsqueda de un estudiante con su cédula en la base de datos para saber cuáles y cuántos cursos ha realizado. La idea es que en la vista "Index" se digite el número de cédula y en la vista "Show" aparezca un listado con todos los cursos que ha realizado. Cabe resaltar que pueden aparecer uno, dos o más cursos.

He intentado realizar la búsqueda con la forma form_tag, con el método find y aún no lo he logrado.

Se espera que aparezca el listado de cursos realizados al buscar la cédula, pero no me está mostrando nada. Cabe resaltar que sí hay conexión a la base de datos y sí hay datos de ejemplo para mostrar.

Controlador Estudiantes

```
class EstudiantesController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :private_methods, except: [:index, :show]
  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def show
    @e = Estudiante.where(:cedula => @ccconsultar)
  end

  def show_null
  end

  def consultar
  end

private
  def estudiante_params
    params.require(:estudiante).permit(:id, :cedula, :nombre, :apellidos, :nivel, :fecha, :url)
  end
end
```

Vista Index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Consulta de Certificados</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">CONSULTA DE CERTIFICADOS</h1>
    <p></p>
      <%= form_tag("/estudiantes/show", method: "get") do %>
        <div class="text-center"><h3>Digite la cédula a consultar:</h3></div>
          <%= label_tag(@ccconsultar, "") %>
          <div align="center"><%= text_field_tag(@ccconsultar) %></div><br>
          <div align="center"><%= submit_tag("Consultar") %></div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</body>
```

Vista Show

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Consulta de Certificados</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Información de los Cursos Realizados</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Cedula</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Nivel</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Descargar</th>
      </tr>
      <% @e.each do |f| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.id %></td>
        <td><%= f.cedula %></td>
        <td><%= f.nombre %></td>
        <td><%= f.apellidos %></td>
        <td><%= f.nivel %></td>
        <td><%= f.fecha %></td>
        <td><a href="https://www.riesgocero.co/consultar-certificados/Certificados/CertificadoPDF.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Descargar</a></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div align="center"><a href="/" button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Regresar</a></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola Alvaro, bienvenido a SO en español! Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/299576/edit) tu pregunta para mostrar el código como texto en lugar de utilizar imágenes.

Comment: En cuanto al error, seguramente no te muestra nada debido a que en la acción `show` del controlador el valor de `@ccconsultar` es `nil` ya que en ningún lado le asignas valor; ¿cómo se llamada el modelo?

Comment: El modelo se llama `estudiante.rb`
Pero a pesar de que quito la línea `@ccconsultar = nil` del método `index`, me sigue apareciendo vacía. Creo que el problema es al capturar la variable `@ccconsultar`

Comment: @Gerry, sí me lograste entender?

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la acción `show`:

```
def show
  @e = Estudiante.where(:cedula => @ccconsultar)
end
```

La variable `@ccconsultar` no está asignada en ningún lado, por eso su contenido es `nil`. Debes de asignarle valor dentro de la misma acción (o en algún *callback*); por ejemplo:

```
def show
  @ccconsultar = ModeloCedula.find(params_cedula)
  @e = Estudiante.where(cedula: @ccconsultar)
end
```

Lo anterior es tomando el código tal como lo muestras, sin embargo me parece que estás confundiendo/mezclando los conceptos, pues lo que realmente necesitas es encontrar al `Estudiante` con una `cedula` dada por el usuario en la vista; esto lo lograrías así:

```
def show
  @estudiante = Estudiante.find_by(cedula: params[:cedula])
end
```

Para que funcione, debes especifiar el nombre `cedula` en la forma en el `input` dentro de la vista *index.html.erb*:

```
<%= form_tag("/estudiantes/show", method: "get") do %>
  <div class="text-center"><h3>Digite la cédula a consultar:</h3></div>
  <%= label_tag(@ccconsultar, "") %>
  <div align="center"><%= text_field_tag(@ccconsultar, name: "cedula") %></div><br>
  <div align="center"><%= submit_tag("Consultar") %></div>
<% end %>
```

No veo la necesidad para utilizar la variable `@ccconsultar`, creo que podrías omitirla por completo, ya que no requieres un objeto como tal, simplemente un campo de texto llamado `cedula`.

Por último, debes modificar la vista *show.html.erb* ya que actualmente estás desplegando múltiples estudiantes, pero el código anterior únicamente te traerá uno (le que corresponde a la cédula) y lo que requieres iterar son sus **cursos**. Asumiendo que el modelo `Estudiante` tiene la relación correcta al modelo de cursos (i.e. `has_many :cursos`, considerando que el modelo se llama `Curso`), entonces harías algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>...</th>
  </tr>
  <% @estudiante.cursos.each do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.id %></td>
    <td><%= f.nombre %></td>
    <td><%= f.... %></td>
    <td><%= f.... %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Las columnas deben coincidir con las que existan (y quieras mostrar) en el modelo `Curso`.

Comment: Mil gracias por tu atención y dedicación. La cuestión es que aún me sigue apareciendo vacía la lista.
En la lista de la vista `show` pueden aparecer uno, dos o más items, pero siento que el problema radica es a la hora de capturar la variable.
En la base de datos ya tengo una variable cedula, por eso creé la variabla `@ccconsultar` eso no lo confundiría?
Hice cada una de las mejoras que me sugeriste y no he logrado obtener el resultado esperado.
De la única manera, hasta el momento, que logré que me listara un alumno fue agregando una línea de código en el controlador:

Comment: `def show
    @ccconsultar = "1066572739"
    @e = Estudiante.where(:cedula => @ccconsultar)
  end
  `

Comment: @AlvaroAndresHernandez Probablemente no esté llegando el parámetro correctamente. ¿Podrías mostrarme los parámetros que envía la forma? Esto lo puedes ver en el log del servidor, cuando haces el _request_ te muestra los parámetros enviados.

Comment: Started GET "/estudiantes/show?commit=Consultar" for ::1 at 2019-10-09 14:20:28 -0500
Processing by EstudiantesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Consultar"}
  Rendering estudiantes/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Estudiante Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `estudiantes`.* FROM `estudiantes` WHERE `estudiantes`.`cedula` IS NULL
  ↳ app/views/estudiantes/show.html.erb:24
  Rendered estudiantes/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 21.2ms | Allocations: 659)
Completed 200 OK in 320ms (Views: 297.0ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms | Allocations: 11162)

Comment: @AlvaroAndresHernandez La forma no está enviando el valor, ¿hiciste el ajuste recomendado?, ¿podrías mostrar el HTML ya generado de `index` (agrégalo en tu pregunta)?

Comment: modifiqué el código de la vista `index` y al intentar cargar la vista me aparece un error de sintaxis, sucede cuando agregamos este tramo de código `id: "cedula"`

`<%= form_tag("/estudiantes/show", method: "get") do %>
      <div class="text-center"><h3>Digite la cédula a consultar:</h3></div>
      <%= label_tag(@ccconsultar, "") %>
      <div align="center"><%= text_field_tag(@ccconsultar), id: "cedula" %></div><br>
      <div align="center"><%= submit_tag("Consultar") %></div>
    <% end %>`

Comment: @AlvaroAndresHernandez Había un error en mi código (paréntesis mal puesto); revisa el ajuste en esa línea e intenta de nuevo.

Comment: Entonces en ese orden de ideas cómo quedaría esa línea?

Comment: @AlvaroAndresHernandez Tal como está en la respuesta (ya la edité): `<%= text_field_tag(@ccconsultar, name: "cedula") %>`.